# Selenium (python) explicit wait timeout error

Tags: python, selenium, timeout, webdriverwait

I'm trying to automate a process that utilizes a webserver for various computational tasks. There are multiple tasks on multiple pages, so I'm using explicit waits. This works for everything except one particular task, which takes 5-7 minutes to complete (much longer than anything else).

Whenever I try the following:

```
def next5():
    try:
        myElem5 = WebDriverWait(driver, 600).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, '#fmdsetup > table > tbody > tr:nth-child(2) > td > input[type="radio"]')))
        next5 = driver.find_element_by_class_name('nav_entry')
        next5.click()
    except TimeoutException:
    print("Timed out waiting for page to load (next5)")
```

I receive the TimeoutException print statement. I've tried longer wait times, but it always times out. The weird thing is that it throws back the TimeoutException before 10 minutes has passed.

Also, the script works perfectly if I simply use a sleep function:

```
def next5():
    time.sleep(600)
    next5 = driver.find_element_by_class_name('nav_entry')
    next5.click()
```

As I said before, I have multiple instances of `next<#>()` functions that work perfectly, and only differ in the wait time. What's different about this situation, and how can I make it work?

Answer (score 0):

Since:

```
def next5():
    try:
        myElem5 = WebDriverWait(driver, 600).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, '#fmdsetup > table > tbody > tr:nth-child(2) > td > input[type="radio"]')))
        next5 = driver.find_element_by_class_name('nav_entry')
        next5.click()
    except TimeoutException:
    print("Timed out waiting for page to load (next5)")
```

and

```
def next5():
    time.sleep(600)
    next5 = driver.find_element_by_class_name('nav_entry')
    next5.click()
```

are different and the first one does not work and the second one works, I can say that the problem is with `myElem5` element. It is not clickable at all, so it makes no sense to add wait time, or this element doesn't exists in the DOM. What exactly is in your case, I cannot say. Try to look exactly, if element is in the DOM and it is clickable. Try to do the same manually and than debug. I think you will find a problem.

EDIT: according your feedback you do like this:

```
def next5(counter=1):
    try:
        if counter == 5:
            WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.url_contains(("the new url, where elem 5 exists")))
        myElem5 = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable(
            (By.CSS_SELECTOR, '#fmdsetup > table > tbody > tr:nth-child(2) > td > input[type="radio"]')))
        next5 = driver.find_element_by_class_name('nav_entry')
        next5.click()
        counter += 1
    except TimeoutException:
        print("Timed out waiting for page to load (next5)")
```

PS make sure that this element is not in `iframe/frame` if yes, firstly you have to switch on it and only then this element will be ready to interact with it. You can use this approach:

```
WebDriverWait(driver, 600).until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((By.XPATH, "//xpath/to/frame")))
# do your stuff
driver.switch_to.default_content()
```

Comment: Ok, now that you mention it, the DOM may be a problem. This page load is different than the rest, because it goes

page -> blank screen -> page (that `next5` operates on).

How can I make the script ignore the blank page and only operate on the desired page?

Comment: does url changes as well?

Comment: Yes, the url changes. The source code of the blank page is `<!-- -->`.

Comment: The url then stays the same for the next page, with a few `<!-- -->` at the top (that accumulate as the process on the blank page progresses). So the blank page url is the same as the url of the page I want `next5()` to interact with.

Comment: Hmmm... I used your suggestion, but the script is still returning a timeout error. I also tried increasing the wait times with no change.

Comment: Than I think it is the case, when you have to use `time.sleep()`, when counter = 5. If you are satisfied with my help, please mark my answer by clicking on the grey check button below downvote button.